# Ransack not working with polymorphic column type (uninitialized constant)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I have set up Ransack as per http://railscasts.com/episodes/370-ransack?view=asciicast and it's functioning fine to search most of the columns in the Orders table using the orders#index controller.

However, it won't search orderable_type or orderable_id, the two columns that store polymorphic associations with other models. Does anyone know why, or how do get around this?

Model:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :quantity
  belongs_to :orderable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :delivery
  belongs_to :requisition
```

Controller:

```
  def index
    @search = Order.search(params[:q])
    @orders = @search.result
  end
```

View:

```
= search_form_for @search do |f|
  .field
    = f.label :orderable_type_matches, "Type"
    = f.text_field :orderable_type_matches
  .field
    = f.label :created_at_gteq, "Created between"
    = f.text_field :created_at_gteq, 'data-behaviour' => 'datepicker'
    = f.label :created_at_lteq, "and"
    = f.text_field :created_at_lteq, 'data-behaviour' => 'datepicker'
  .actions
    = f.submit "Search"
```

And the error I receive is:

> uninitialized constant Order::Orderable Extracted source (around line #13):
>
> 10:     = f.text_field :location_place_matches 11:   .field 12:     =
>   f.label :orderable_type_matches, "Type" 13:     = f.text_field
>   :orderable_type_matches 14:   .field 15:     = f.label
>   :created_at_gteq, "Created between" 16:     = f.text_field
>   :created_at_gteq, 'data-behaviour' => 'datepicker'

For the life of me I don't understand why it's treating orderable_type differently to all the other columns - can anyone help to fix?

Comment: The Ransack wiki on searching polymorphic associations might help: https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/wiki/Polymorphic-searches

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really find a way to fix this, but a developer friend suggested a way I could achieve the same result which might help others. He said I should just hardcode the form field and not rely on the Ransack helpers to create the dropdown menu. So that's what I did and it works :-)